# Fixing a ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 1)

Tags: jupyter-notebook, valueerror

I am trying to run some visualizations, and I am trying to point it to the new data by modifying the path and folders in the "initialization" cell of the Jupyter Notebook:

**Path**: '/global/scratch/file_directory/file_name/file_name_1/'
**Folders**: name1 name2 name3 name4

Solid is found in the .ase module.

Running my code:

```
hd = '/global/scratch/file_directory/file_name/file_name_1/'

dirs = [hd+'name1', hd+'name2', hd+'name3', hd+'name4']

names = ['name1'  'name2'  'name3'  'name4']

nno = len(names)

#Generate an object for each calculation using the Solid class:
objs = [Solid(names[i], dirs[i]) for i in range(nno)]
name1, name2, name3, name4= objs
```

gets this error, and I'm not sure what to fix to get it to run:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-d3e61ce6b79f> in <module>
     12 #Generate an object for each calculation using the Solid class:
     13 objs = [Solid(names[i], dirs[i]) for i in range(nno)]
---> 14 name1, name2, name3, name4= objs
     15 
     16 

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

In `names`, you have missed out the commas separating each element. This leads to it them being implicitly concentrated to `name1name2name3name4`.
This results in `nno == 1`

We can see this using a dataclass (just to make printing objects more descriptive):

```py
@dataclass
class Solid:
    name: str
    dir: str

objs = [Solid(names[i], dirs[i]) for i in range(nno)]

print(objs)  # [Solid(name='name1name2name3name4', dir='/global/scratch/file_directory/file_name/file_name_1/name1')]
```

Adding the commas results in

```py
print(objs)

"""
names = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4']

[
    Solid(name='name1', dir='/global/scratch/file_directory/file_name/file_name_1/name1'),
    Solid(name='name2', dir='/global/scratch/file_directory/file_name/file_name_1/name2'),
    Solid(name='name3', dir='/global/scratch/file_directory/file_name/file_name_1/name3'),
    Solid(name='name4', dir='/global/scratch/file_directory/file_name/file_name_1/name4')
]
"""
```

This is a sort of **soft-error** because it does not crash the program, only cause unexpected behaviour.